# Are all animals called by summoning jutsu able to speak?

Tags: naruto

I remember that all toads summoned by Jiraiya or Naruto were able to speak. I know that Tsunade's snail or Orochimaru's snake is able to speak, too. But what about the Ninken? I know that Pakkun can talk, but what about Kiba's Ninken and the others (I know around 3–4 dogs out of 9)? I know that the Pain summonings aren't able to talk.

Is there a rule that every animal can talk, or something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they didn't explicitly show whether they can talk or not, but one thing is for sure: that Pakkun can talk.

Kiba's Akamaru can't talk, so we can assume that other dogs of Kakashi also can't talk (since there is no evidence in the manga or anime).

So in order to answer your question: **"Is there a rule that every animal can talk, or something like this?"** I would say **"No, it is not mandatory for animals to talk."**

Answer (score 2):

No, not every summoned animal can speak.

For example when Naruto learned summoning the toads, he first summoned a tadpole, which was not able to talk. Now you could say it was just too young to speak, but it didn't make any vocal sound at all, like crying etc.

As far as I know none of the Inazuka's clan's dogs are able to talk either, nor do I think that Itachi's crows were able to speak.