# Why can't Akamaru talk like Pakkun?

Tags: naruto

How come Pakkun can talk to Kakashi when summoned (in fact almost all summoned toads can talk), but Akamaru, who was brought up by Kiba since he was a pup, cannot speak?

Comment: Strongly related (duplicate?): https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/are-all-animals-called-by-summoning-jutsu-able-to-speak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although both Pakkun and Akamaru are considered [ninken](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ninken) (dogs with heightened senses and abilities, and as such, working alongside shinobis), the only difference between them is Pakkun is actually a Summon (much like sage toads). Summons are basically supernatural animal spirits and they take on anthropomorphic qualities  like talking, using weapons, wearing clothes etc. Akamaru is basically a highly trained dog that can use ninjutsu.

Atleast, [Akamaru tried talking.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xDUwYbVYwQ)